# How to change the interlineate within a parbox environment?

Tags: minipage

I'm using a parbox within a tabular environment.

```
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|r|r|}
    \hline
    {\bf Ensayo} &    {\bf 1} &    {\bf 2} &    {\bf 3} &    {\bf 4} & {\bf 5} & {\bf Promedio} & \parbox[c]{2cm}{\centering\bf Desv. Estándar} \\
    \hline
    \parbox[c]{2cm}{\centering\bf Altura (cm)} &     3.8999  &     3.9002 &  3.9003 &  3.9004 & 3.8995 & 3.9000 & 0.0003 \\
    \parbox[c]{2cm}{\centering\bf Periodo (s)} &     10.748 &     10.740 &     10.772 & 10.770 & 10.772 & 10.7603 & 0.0127 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
```

And this the result:[image]

I'm wondering how to stretch the vertical separation between one and another line, I mean the interlineate within the parbox environment. For example to reduce the space between "Altura" and "(cm)". Also, I don't like the \hline crossing the text in "Desv. Estándar", I want it below the text, not crossing the text, how could I do that?

Regards
Jassy

This is the new code:

```
    \begin{tabular}{|l|*{7}{S[table-format=2.4, table-number-alignment=center]|}}
    \hline
    \thead[c]{Ensayo} & {\thead{1}} & {\thead{2}} & {\thead{3}} & {\thead{4}} &{ \thead{5}} & {\thead{Promedio}} & {\thead{Desv.\\ Estándar}} \\
    \hline
    \thead{Altura\\ (cm)} & 3.8999 & 3.9002 & 3.9003 & 3.9004 & 3.8995 & 3.9000 & 0.0003 \\
    \thead{Periodo \\ (s)} & 10.748 & 10.740 & 10.772 & 10.770 & 10.772 & 10.7603 & 0.0127 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `\parbox`: use the `\thead` command from `makecell`. It allows for line breaks in cells and a common formatting. Also, you can have a nice alignment of numbers with the `S` column type from `siunitx`. If  you prefer a simpler code, without alignment of the decimal dot, use `c` columns` (second solution):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{array, siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\normalsize}

\begin{document}

\noindent \begin{tabular}{|l|*{7}{S[table-format=2.4, table-number-alignment=center]|}}
\hline
\thead[lc]{Ensayo} & {\thead{1}} & {\thead{2}} & {\thead{3}} & {\thead{4}} &{ \thead{5}} & {\thead{Promedio}} & {\thead{Desv.\\ Estándar}} \\
\hline
\thead{Altura\\ (cm)} & 3.8999 & 3.9002 & 3.9003 & 3.9004 & 3.8995 & 3.9000 & 0.0003 \\
\thead{Periodo\\ (s)} & 10.748 & 10.740 & 10.772 & 10.770 & 10.772 & 10.7603 & 0.0127 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\vskip 1cm

\noindent \begin{tabular}{|l|*{7}{c|}}
\hline
\thead[lc]{Ensayo} & \thead{1} & \thead{2} & \thead{3} & \thead{4} & \thead{5} & \thead{Promedio} & \thead{Desv.\\ Estándar} \\
\hline
\thead{Altura\\ (cm)} & 3.8999 & 3.9002 & 3.9003 & 3.9004 & 3.8995 & 3.9000 & 0.0003 \\
\thead{Periodo\\ (s)} & 10.748 & 10.740 & 10.772 & 10.770 & 10.772 & 10.7603 & 0.0127 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about that option. It certainly looks a lot better than mine, but still the second row seems to be left aligned, how to make all of them to be centered. I also copied your code into my document, but the result is not the same as yours, still vertical separation is too much for me, I don't know why, but id doesn't look like yours!

Comment: First point: the second row *is* centred ( (look at the lastcolun-second row). I think it' a visual effect due to the fact that most numbers in the second row have 3 decimal digits and 2 integer digits, while in the first row they have 4 decimal digits and 1 integer digit. If you don't like it, change the column type to `c`, but you'll lose the alignment of the decimal dot. For the second point, a minimal working example would be welcome.

Comment: [![captura][1]][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/PnoNl.png puedes ver la imagen en el link por favor, es que no sé bien cómo adjuntar imágenes en comentarios! Gracias

Comment: I see one difference: clearly, you added a line break in the first cell of the second row. However, this doesn't explain the difference in the interlining inside `\thead`. So, again a working *code* would be nice.

Comment: Yes, in the general preamble, not the optional argument of `\thead`.

Comment: The code is exactly the same than yours, except for the line break, I also tried without this line break and the result is the same. Here is the code: 'code' \begin{tabular}{|l|*{7}{S[table-format=2.4, table-number-alignment=center]|}}
\hline
\thead[c]{Ensayo} & {\thead{1}} & {\thead{2}} & {\thead{3}} & {\thead{4}} &{ \thead{5}} & {\thead{Promedio}} & {\thead{Desv.\\ Estándar}} \\
\hline
\thead{Altura\\ (cm)} & 3.8999 & 3.9002 & 3.9003 & 3.9004 & 3.8995 & 3.9000 & 0.0003 \\
\thead{Periodo \\ (s)} & 10.748 & 10.740 & 10.772 & 10.770 & 10.772 & 10.7603 & 0.0127 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

Comment: I don't know how to add code to the comments! I'm sorry. When you say to change the column type for c, do you mean in the tabular environment? \begin{tabular}{|c|....? Because I already tried that but the alignment is still the same! Btw, I'm using sharelatex, do you think it has something to do with the alignment and the interlineate problem?

Comment: I've updated my code to add the smae line break  as you (see my updated answer). For the code, the  simplest is to edit you question and change the code or add the new one.

Comment: With your new code, I don't have any difference with my code. Do you still have one on your system?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's a little bit clearer now, I prefer the second option. Do you have any suggestions about the interlineate? Yes, the "new code" is actually yours, I just posted it because I couldn't add it here as a comment, as you requested to see the code.

Comment: The difference in interlining probably comes from your preamble. Could post a minimal *full* code which reproduces the problem?

Comment: Sure! It must be because of the preamble, besides the "use packages" sentences, I have another one "\def\baselinestretch{1.5}", and I guess it's because of it. But I like the interlining of the document, I don't want to change it, I only want to make it smaller within the table, do you think is possible?...If you still need the full code, please let me know.

Comment: I'll test with `1.5`. However let me tell you this is *very* large (almost double spacing), and furthermore, it does the same for foonotes and list environments. The sensible way to increase interlining is to use the `setspace` package. If you look at the details in it, you'll see that `\onehalfspacing` is *not* `\setstretch{1.5}` as one might naively think, but a little less (~1.25-1.33, depending on the fontsize).

Comment: Add these lines to your  preamble: `\usepackagesetspace,etoolbox} \AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\singlespacing}`.